# Problems accessing a file on iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io

I have a Problem with that code written in Object c++ and Xcode 5:

```
NSLog(@"%@",pathToFile);
    NSString *outputFileName = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.txt"];

    FILE* fileo = fopen([outputFileName UTF8String], "w");
    if (fileo) fclose(fileo);
    fileo = fopen([outputFileName UTF8String], "a");
    if (!fileo) { perror("fopen"); NSLog(@" Wrong"); } else { NSLog(@"Nothing Wrong"); }

    //Open the PDF source file:
    //  FILE* filei = fopen("c:\\pdf\\somepdf.pdf", "rb");
    FILE* filei = fopen([pathToFile UTF8String], "rb");
if (!filei) { perror("fopen"); NSLog(@" Wrong"); } else { NSLog(@"Nothing Wrong"); }

    if (filei && fileo)
    {
```

the Problem is that filei is every time Nil and I down't know why,!
I think the Problem is the pathtoFile: 
it is: pathToFile

```
__NSCFString *  @"file:///private/var/mobile/Applications/3D02CBE0-6A8E-4709-B6EF-B6793E19F4F4/Documents/Inbox/Published_071032-8.pdf"

0x145c53e0
```

The code works great on Simulator but not on the iPhone!
Has someone an idea whats wrong?

Working Directory maybe but there is no way to change it in xcode 5.

Comment: Title says C, question body says "Object C++" (whatever that is), tags say C++. Now what?

Comment: (Yay, and the all-caps username...)

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/pl/minor_differences/capslock

Answer (score 0):

Yes seems like the Path of your file is the problem. Im even sure priced that you saw something like `@"file://..."` because the unix file system is based on the path directly e.g `/var/mobile/.../`

The next I would recommend you is to check where you define the pathToFile string. Maybe it is already out of scope because it was created on the stack because you create it within the same function/method.

Thats maybe the reason why it is `NULL`/ `nil`.

maybe a solution: create the path based on `NSBundle` class + don't use `file://` -paths.

Let me know if it works or any additional help is required.
Thank you 
regards

Comment: THx that was the problem!

Comment: I think I have also problems with writeToFile:atomically:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 2.0